# Access log system for php yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, hadoop, nginx, yii

I am using PHP to develop a website, specifically using **YII 2 framewor**k. The web server is using `Nginx`, `PHP engine` is php-fpm. The question is I want to track which user accessed which `webpage` URL address with parameters. `Yii2` itself has a logging system, but that's mainly for error and debug purpose. I know nginx has logging system can record access log, but I need to record the exact userid, username which is in my database, I think `nginx` cannot record this.

I think of to record these info into another Mysql table when everytime user access a page, but I am worried the table may grow very quickly, seems using relational database may not be a good idea.

Should I use **Hadoop**? Or other common practice to solve this kind of problem? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to

> track which user accessed which webpage URL address with parameters,

nginx access log is a better choice because mysql will hurt your performance a lot.

Assume user id is a parameter `uid` in query string, you can custom nginx's access log by adding a field `$arg_uid`. If user id is part of uri, you may need config location with a regexp to capture it.

If user id can not be obtained from request directly, there must be a token correlated with one and only one user which can be retrived from mysql or redis. In this case, there are 2 methods:

1. return user id as a header for example X-UID in php, then add variable `$upstream_http_X_UID` in access log. If you do not want to return this header to clients, add a directive `proxy_hide_header X-UID;` to delete this header from php response.
2. build nginx with [nginx-lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) module and write a piece of lua script for `log_by_lua` directive in which query the user id from mysql or redis according to that token. Then custom nginx's access log by adding the user id variable.

According to your specific scene, choose the best solution. 
I hope this helps you.

Comment: I cannot put uid in every request parameter, because I have session and cookies to track them. Thus your suggestion is great, I can output uid in http response header and let nginx record them. Later I plan to use Logstash tools to analyze nginx log. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Hadoop but I've run in the past into issues because of storing millions of pageviews inside MySQL table (40GB).

But basically the issue is not storing but how are you actually going to use that data.

MySQL can handle a lot of data I think but depending on how you need to display it you might either have some cronjob doing some optimizations and saving in a different format to another table so its easy to display it, or either learn about some NoSQL databases that might help.

Btw, I've heard that guys at [GetClicky Analytics](https://clicky.com/) were using plain text files for storing data so.. I guess you could also go with that option.

Some other ideas if you choose to go with MySQL:

- Maybe look into table partitioning?
- Maybe create a separate database and a separate database connection in Yii2 and use that db connection to store access log only? This way you don't mix the access data with app data
- Maybe both?

Comment: Your answer give me hints too. What I actually want to do is to know which user or what kind of user(age, gender, etc.) like to read which kind of blog posts, and later we can remind them similar new posts. Thus we don't need to store all history logs. One month data may be enough,  or at most six months, that's not big deal, and can be saved in Mysql.